# Python Tuple Unpacking

Tags: python, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

If I have

```
 nums_and_words = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')]
```

and would like

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
words= ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

How would I do that in a Pythonic way? It took me a minute to realize why the following doesn't work

```
nums, words = [(el[0], el[1]) for el in nums_and_words]
```

I'm curious if someone can provide a similar manner of achieving the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), then unpack:

```
nums_and_words = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')]
nums, words = zip(*nums_and_words)
```

Actually, this "unpacks" twice: First, when you pass the list of lists to `zip` with `*`, then when you distribute the result to the two variables.

You can think of `zip(*list_of_lists)` as 'transposing' the argument:

```
   zip(*[(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')])
== zip(  (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three') )
== [(1, 2, 3), ('one', 'two', 'three')]
```

Note that this will give you tuples; if you really need lists, you'd have to `map` the result:

```
nums, words = map(list, zip(*nums_and_words))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using List comprehension ..

```
nums = [nums_and_words[x][0] for x in xrange(len(nums_and_words)) ]
words = [nums_and_words[x][1] for x in xrange(len(nums_and_words)) ]
```

Testing if this works

```
print nums ,'&', words
```

Answer (score 0):

Just unzip and create lists:

```
nums = list(zip(*nums_and_words)[0])
word = list(zip(*nums_and_words)[1])
```

See the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) documentation.

Comment: I'd hoped to avoid splitting it over two lines. The initial setup I had which I was hoping to get away from was... num = filter(lambda x: x[0], num_and_words) and words = filter(lambda x: x[1], num_and_words)